# How to improve the browser garbage collection phase of web app?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, garbage-collection

I have optimized my php/javascript web app to be fairly fast, but an analysis with the google speed tracer shows a 230ms garbage collection phase. What is it, as pertains to the speed tracer results, and what are some guidelines in improving it?

Comment: 230ms? Really? Is this actually your greatest problem right now?

Comment: it's the one I know the least about, so I would say yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold on to the objects, then the garbage collection phase will at least be delayed for it to matter, page is already rendered etc. Browser will do a garbage collect if for some reason in your Javascript code you are vacating objects, assigning objects to null, or replacing objects.

Comment: That makes definite sense, as I usually try to clear my objects and variables immediately after use — a habit left over from c++ days. Thanks!